# Node.JS Object creation issue "User is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im doing my firs Node.JS application by following "Learn NodeJS by Building 10 Projects" and at the third application the task is to build a user login/registration site. The problem I'm having might be related to Javascript or Node, but I'm not sure.

Error:

```
TypeError: User is not a function
at .../routes/users.js:75:17
...
```

and at line 75 in the users.js file I try to create the newUser object:

```
var User = require('../models/user.js');
....
var newUser = new User({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        name: name,
        password: password
    });
```

The user's class is in my modules folder looks as following:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//user schema
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type:String,
        index:true},
    password:{type:String},
    email:{type:String},
    name:{type:String},
    profileimage:{type:String}
});

var User = module.export = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    newUser.save(callback);   
}
```

And using my limited javascript knowledge I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong...

Comment: var User = `module.export` --- must be `module.exports`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var User = module.export = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

should have been

```
 var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
 //                      ^
```